# I need to place three decimal places when i run my report

Tags: php, database, decimal

My PHP code runs a specific report but when it displays with many decimal places. I want my code to round off to 3 decimal places. Any ideas. Below is my code.

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>

   <tr>
    <td><?php    echo $row['dategenerated'];      ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['invoiceno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['outletname']; ?></td>

    <td><?php echo     $row['businessregistrationno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['barcode']; ?></td>

    <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno'] ); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['productname']; ?></td>

    <!--<td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno']); ?></td>-->
    <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno'])  * $row['price']; ?></td>
    <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno'])  * $row['price'] * $row['vat'] - (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered']) / $row['packno'])  * $row['price']  ; ?></td>
            <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno']) * $row['price'] * $row['vat']; ?></td>



   </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
echo number_format($val,3);
```

Or

```
echo round($val,3);
```

Comment: How should i implement it in my code suppose for the line                                         <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno'] ); ?></td>    Any ideas

Comment: <?php $upd_qty=$row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered']; ?>
 <td class="char-align" align="right" style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo round($upd_qty/$row['packno'],3); ?></td>

Comment: for price i got error.. Any idea how to put round 2 in this part of code    <td class="char-align" align="right"  style="padding-right:70px;" ><?php echo (($row['QtyOrdered'] - $row['QtyDelivered'] ) / $row['packno'])  * $row['price']; ?></td>

Comment: just mention 2 instead of 3 in my previous comment